# How to BottomAppBar backgroundColor transparent

Tags: flutter, transparent, bottomappbar

I want the BottomAppBar to be transparent and show what's going on，so here's my code.

```dart
class BottomTabNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomTabNavigationState createState() => _BottomTabNavigationState();
}

class _BottomTabNavigationState extends State<BottomTabNavigation>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  PageController _pageController;
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: 0,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          _buildScaffold(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Scaffold _buildScaffold() {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          PostsPage(),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 28,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.6,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomAppBar(),
    );
  }

  Widget _bottomAppBar() {
    return BottomAppBar(
      elevation: 6,
      notchMargin: 8.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: CustomCircularNotchedRectangle(),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 26,
                  icon: Icon(IconFont.icon_home),
                  color: _currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentIndex = 0;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 26,
                  icon: Icon(IconFont.icon_search2),
                  color: _currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentIndex = 1;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 56,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 28,
                  icon: Icon(IconFont.icon_message),
                  color: _currentIndex == 2 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentIndex = 2;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 28,
                  icon: Icon(IconFont.icon_user1),
                  color: _currentIndex == 3 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentIndex = 3;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

The result is black (you can't see the rest if you set it to white).

To achieve transparency, I wrapped the Scaffold in a Stack and set its background color, but it still didn't work.

How do you solve this problem？

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

all what you need is to add

```
extendBody: true,
```

property to `Scaffold`

Comment: Thanks for coming back, this property solves the problem, but if you add padding to the bottom it still has a white background

Comment: Short and to the point answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Stack` and separate `PageView` from `Scaffold body`:

```dart
class _BottomTabNavigationState extends State<DemoWidget>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  PageController _pageController;
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: 0,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: PageView(
              controller: _pageController,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Empty Body 1'),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Empty Body 2'),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Empty Body 3'),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Empty Body 4'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                size: 28,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.6,
            ),
            floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
            bottomNavigationBar: _bottomAppBar(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _bottomAppBar() {
    return BottomAppBar(
      elevation: 6,
      notchMargin: 8.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 26,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  color: _currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentIndex = 0;
                      _pageController.jumpToPage(_currentIndex);
                    });
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 26,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  color: _currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentIndex = 1;
                      _pageController.jumpToPage(_currentIndex);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 56,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 28,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.message),
                  color: _currentIndex == 2 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentIndex = 2;
                      _pageController.jumpToPage(_currentIndex);
                    });
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 28,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle),
                  color: _currentIndex == 3 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentIndex = 3;
                      _pageController.jumpToPage(_currentIndex);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

[image: ScreenShot]

**Remember** that to use `Padding` at the end of your every child of `PageView` for overlapping by `BottomAppBar`, you can use `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` size for `BottomPadding`.

Comment: I just tried it, and if the PageView contains rolling widgets, you can't manipulate them